# Track the exact location of IP address

Tags: java, swing, networking, geolocation, ip

I am trying to create an app to find the exact location of IP address. I did some research on IP addresses and many more. But whenever I try to locate an IP address it provides the location of Internet Service Provider. I want to track the exact geolocation or long & lat of that place. So can anyone help me out to let me know how to find the geolocation of Dynamic IP address

Comment: I dont think you can do that you will only get ISP address. Imagine you are just connected to your internet cable how you can get the latitude and longitude from that if that is not a mobile device

Comment: Are you planning on implementing "Big Brother"? This raises severe privacy issues and concerns.

Comment: No bro I am just trying to create a location tracker application just because one week before my gmail and fb account got hacked and I got the IP address(i.e. The dynamic IP) so i couldn't find out the hacker location

Comment: @VighaneshGursale It's unlikely that you will ever find the real address for a given IP. Nevertheless, if you had that exact location, what would you do? Go there and beat the crap out of the guy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information upon which such a service might (hypothetically) be based is not available.  Ergo, the ISP level information is about as good as you are likely to get for wired IP addresses.

@salocinix wrote:

> "The exact position of an end-user's IP is only store at the ISP database and is normally not given away."

The second part is definitely true.  They don't and shouldn't give away details about their customers' physical locations.  There are obvious privacy concerns with doing that.

But it is quite possible that the ISP **doesn't** store the customer's physical location *at all*.  Certainly, there is no need for them to store it in the form of longitude and latitude.  Whether they need to store it depends on who owns the wires.  In Australia for instance, many customers' ISPs don't own the wires that carry the traffic to the customers' dwelling.  In that case, the ISP (in theory) only needs to know the billing address for the customer.  And then there is the case of ISPs who sell internet connectivity for mobile devices ... where the physical location of a given IP address can change on a minute-by-minute basis.

---

> ... just asking because google maps shows the exact location of my PC on map how does it work

The PC is most likely geolocating *itself* via a combination of GPS and triangulation of local wireless base stations.

Comment: I'm not sure that I asking you correct thing assume that if I use the HTML5 geolocation to find the location will thing return the location or it will do the same like showing the ISP location. Don't take me wrong just asking because google maps shows the exact location of my PC on map how does it work

Answer (score 0):

The exact position of an end-user's IP is only store at the ISP database and is normally not given away by the IS-provider. Try out the following link, you'll not achieve much more precision.

http://www.iplocation.net/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to read the [following thread](http://www.nanog.org/mailinglist/mailarchives/old_archive/2008-01/msg00728.html) on **NANOG** which was written by Fred Baker of Cisco, author of 50 network related RFC's.

*Well, let me ask you you think 171.70.120.60 is. I'll give you a hint;
at this instant, there are 72 of us.
Here's another question. Whom would you suspect 171.71.241.89 is?  At
this point in time, I am in Barcelona; if I were home, that would be my
address as you would see it, but my address as I would see it would be
in 10.32.244.216/29. There might be several hundred people you would
see using 171.71.241.89;*

Geolocating is gimmicky at best.