# Determine the location of the session with the IP address

Tags: php, geolocation

Is there a way to get the estimated location from an end-user's IP address using only php?

I did some research on this. Here "[Track the exact location of IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688085/track-the-exact-location-of-ip-address)", they announced that this is not possible.

But I mean, take the location of the service provider.

Even if I could only describe his country, that would be enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use server global array to take ip :

```
ip_user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

and use this function for get country name :

```
function ip_details($ip_user) 
{
    $json       = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip_user}");
    $details    = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}
```

Comment: Do note that if the server is behind a proxy(which is likely) this will return the local ip not the remote ip.